# convert 3 columns data frame to matrix

Tags: r

I have the following input:

```
A   B   0
A   C   1
B   C   1
```

Which I would like to convert to a 3x3 matrix:

```
    A   B   C
A   0   0   1
B   0   0   1
C   1   1   0
```

How should I do this in R? The above is just to give an idea of what I aim to do. Below is my data. I cut this down to 15 obs but my dataset has 500 and the ticker set are the same for ticker1 and ticker2. Thus I would want an n x n matrix.

```
ticker1 ticker2 edge
AEPI    AVAV    0.044210322
AEPI    BOKF    0.008021954
AEPI    CMSB    0.001986887
AEPI    RON     0.006777085
AEPI    CAKE    0.045002911
APPL    COH     0.042760407
APPL    SWZA    0.040913242
APPL    DRIV    0.047699102
APPL    CXP     0.014103206
MSCR    FIVN    0.008781475
MSCR    HOS     0.040222645
MSCR    HDSN    0.010454853
MSCR    IPWR    0.003376232
MSCR    KELYB   0.000755429
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `base R` methods.  If the first two columns are not `factor` class, convert it to `factor` with `levels` specified so that both the columns have the same `levels`.  Then use `xtabs` to convert it to 'wide' format and change the values in the lower half by adding with the transpose of the 'm1'

```
df1[1:2] <- lapply(df1[1:2], factor, levels = LETTERS[1:3])
m1 <- xtabs(v3~v1 + v2, df1)
names(dimnames(m1)) <- NULL
m1 + t(m1)
#  A B C
#A 0 0 1
#B 0 0 1
#C 1 1 0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("A", "A", "B"), v2 = c("B", "C", "C"), 
v3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: thanks. but can I get a table with columns to be A B C and rows with the first var or label to be A B C as well? I will eventually need to export this to a csv and read this matrix into a network using statnet or igraph

Comment: @duckman  Do you meant that it needs to be convertd to `data.frame`.  Not really getting your comment.  Perhaps `as.data.frame.matrix(m1 + t(m1))`

Answer (score 1):

Another way with `igraph` and data from @akrun

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("A", "A", "B"), v2 = c("B", "C", "C"), 
                      v3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

library(igraph)

g=graph.data.frame(df1,directed=FALSE)
get.adjacency(g,attr='v3',spars=FALSE)
```

**Edit 1**

```
    df2 <- read.table(text="ticker1 ticker2 edge
               AEPI    AVAV    0.044210322
               AEPI    BOKF    0.008021954
               AEPI    CMSB    0.001986887
               AEPI    RON     0.006777085
               AEPI    CAKE    0.045002911
               APPL    COH     0.042760407
               APPL    SWZA    0.040913242
               APPL    DRIV    0.047699102
               APPL    CXP     0.014103206
               MSCR    FIVN    0.008781475
               MSCR    HOS     0.040222645
               MSCR    HDSN    0.010454853
               MSCR    IPWR    0.003376232
               MSCR    KELYB   0.000755429",header=TRUE)

g=graph.data.frame(df2,directed=FALSE)
get.adjacency(g,attr='edge',spars=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question. Please have a look

Comment: @duckman please stick to one question and do not add additional things once your question is answered particularly when it can easily be solved with the provided solutions. Furthermore it is always nice when you provide the dataframe in question with`dput`. See my edit above for your additional question